# Request to undelete a moderator-deleted TempleOS question

Tags: discussion, moderation, vote-to-undelete

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50264004/does-templeos-5-03-have-after-egypt-and-other-utilities was deleted. It concerns a fringe operating system called TempleOS. The guy who wrote the operating system is seriously suffering from a mental disorder (*and this is not a joke*).  As a result he has added a lot of religiously oriented names and implications. The innermost code within TempleOS is known as *the oracle*.  This code according to the author is a conduit to speaking to God.

*After Egypt* is a implementation of the oracle, a utility that permits users to "climb Mt Horeb" with a rendered "stick figure Moses".  This is presented in a YouTube video titled ["TempleOS AfterEgypt"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ETqBJZudpw).  At 0:23 in the linked video, the opening screen of *AfterEgypt* is seen.

Evan is curious if the utility, which he cannot locate in his copies of TempleOS, is available at a location he cannot identify.  He's curious what might be in it, as in his investigation of the OS, he's become a bit fascinated by the author's descent into mental instability.

I believe the question was mistakenly closed on the surface evidence that *AfterEgypt* is (in other operating systems) a game, and the request was one of finding abandonware (which is clearly outside of Stack Overflow's policy).

Please consider undeleting the question, and be warned that TempleOS is not an operating system for the easily offended, containing both highly religiously oriented wording, and often offensive representations of the programmer's religious interpretations.

Comment: Normally I don't ask for things to be reopened this way, but it is likely the only way it might be reopened.  As this is about as fringe an operating system as one can claim, nobody is going to get 30 upvotes to reopen this question.  I'd be shocked if TempleOS even has 30 users.  TempleOS is weird enough to lend credence to the adage that reality is stranger than fiction.

Comment: And now the META effect kicked in marking it `Off-Topic`

Comment: @Luuklag Well, it sounds very off-topic to me. Can you explain how it's programming-related? Migrating it to SU, like Samuel suggested, might be the best move.

Comment: How is this **not** off topic? Exactly how is this programming related?

Comment: "The guy who wrote the operating system is seriously suffering from a mental disorder". Writing an operating system does that to you sometimes.

Comment: Based on the description of this software from this post, it seems like the best course of action would be to put it inside a paper bag and burn it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorry, [the question initially](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50264004/2) does look like a spammy or VLQ post at first glance. Unfortunately the YouTube video didn't help bolster the context.

I have now undeleted it, please try to provide more supporting info in the question - perhaps even explaining what the software is about?

Also, can you consider if your question is better suited for [Super User](https://superuser.com/about)?

Comment: Thank you.  I fully understand how the queston looks spammy and fake, but the base OS itself appears to be spammy and fake.   Unfortunately, especially for, Terry Davis, it looks so because the author is suffering from mental illness.  I'll ask Evan to clearify the question to make it appear less fake in light of people who have never seen or heard of TempleOS.

Comment: Thanks @Samuel Liew. I spent about an hour trying to find those links for my answer, and then someone else showed me up. Your typical case that happens anytime source migrates from CORE to non-core and gets moved out of a distribution. Except the lack of an audience or documentation makes StackOverflow all the more useful on cases with [tag:templeos]

Comment: I don't see a good reason why it was undeleted. This question is blatantly off-topic.