# Raiders of the lost TempleOS (Harrison Ford impersonator optional)

Tags: discussion, support, tags, migration

Related:

- [Request to undelete a moderator-deleted TempleOS question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367663/request-to-undelete-a-moderator-deleted-templeos-question)
- [Niche technologies and question acceptance and moderation on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367693/niche-technologies-and-question-acceptance-and-moderation-on-stackoverflow)

The tag [templeos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/templeos) is more or less a morass of off-topic general support requests for TempleOS, a niche operating system. They seem to be fairly well written, but unfortunately have a very high off-topic index. Only one or two of the questions are even on-topic for Stack Overflow, and those barely.

Can we do something with these questions? Perhaps a mass migration to Super User (where many of them might find a good home)? All of them seem to have been asked very recently, well within the migration boundary. Mods, can one of you do that?

I checked Super User and I don't see *any* questions that contain the string "TempleOS" nor a TempleOS tag, so these ten questions could form the basis of a TempleOS community on SU without immediately getting closed as duplicates.

Comment: Why do we hate SU again?  I forgot...

Comment: We should encourage them to start a [team](https://stackoverflow.com/teams).

Comment: To start formally: I'm not sure any of the questions is acceptable for SU either. We should just delete these questions (as they also have some haut-gout) and the tag altogether.

Comment: Every one of those questions was asked by the same person within the last 2 days. That really is a niche OS.

Comment: @Turnip see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367693/niche-technologies-and-question-acceptance-and-moderation-on-stackoverflow

Comment: I would actually expect the asker of all of those questions (hint: it's the same person) to know what is and isn't on-topic here.  Questions about a niche OS aren't on-topic here.  Why is this a *discussion* point?  Why aren't we setting fire to this yet??

Comment: @Makoto I was originally going to make this a burninate request, but then I realized that we *could* have on-topic questions about TempleOS. Maybe we don't have any *now*, but we could get some.

Comment: @Makoto I also did know that they were all by the same question-asker, but didn't consider that truly relevant. On SO, we are supposed to judge posts, not posters.

Comment: Anyway, my vote is simple:  less consternation; more irradiation.

Comment: Eh... Are we burninating the tag? All questions but one are closed, and the one that isn't has 4 close votes currently. I say we should perhaps hold off on that for a day, and give the community a little more time to discuss.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I was thinking that we could just let the existing questions get closed and deleted (if that is the judgment of the community). Then, the tag will go away if no one cares to post some good on-topic questions about TempleOS and will stay if someone *does*. Either result seems good.

Comment: I feel like we need to somehow notify [Evan Carroll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/124486/evan-carroll), given that they asked *all* of the questions in that tag. I imagine they might want to post an answer.

Comment: @jpmc26:  Why...?

Comment: @jpmc26:  Let me rephrase and drop the snark.  If we replaced TempleOS with Kali Linux, would that make the situation any different?

Comment: If the tag has a clear main contributor (e.g. >20% of all content), I'd say we should notify him/her about any discussion about the future of it. However, Evan Carroll is already engaged in discussion [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367693/7296893) currently, and that question has overlap with this one. I think involving him here would double the discussion.

Comment: @Makoto Because Evan obviously has a stake in this discussion? And may have insights/expertise we're not considering? O_o Generally, you want people who have expertise in an area and who are affected by discussions/decisions to comment on them... So why *not*?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth If this discussion is duplicating the other one, then maybe one should be *closed*?

Comment: Perhaps. Apparently, the other discussion has taken a turn, with Evan creating [This Area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/117983/os-dev/117988#117988). If that comes through, we could migrate the questions to there. I fear on SU they might not fit in well.

Comment: @jpmc26:  because this smells *too* strongly like an attempt at a hard troll on the site, and our time and energy could be spent doing more important things than unnecessarily discussing what is and is not acceptable on the site with someone who has been on the site for a ***very*** long time.

Comment: Is it me, or there is something weird in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50264004/does-templeos-5-03-have-after-egypt-and-other-utilities), when compared to the deleted answer by the OP? (10k+ only) Is that a puppet account?

Comment: @Camilo Now that you say it, the entire account only has TempleOS answers (on questions by Evan). That looks a bit sock-puppety to me. Perhaps worth a mod flag.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I already noticed that and mod-flagged it. It wouldn't hurt to do so again.

Comment: @RobertColumbia I already flagged, so...

Comment: I don't see any evidence of sock puppets. The answers are very novice-like, expected for someone new to the SE network and format (just look at the initial revisions, they have later been edited by others, and mostly the asker)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ You're not a mod, what you don't see may be seen by others with appropriate tools. And it is suspicious to have 7 upvotes on this answer in a few hours on the first day that Stack Overflow has questions on TempleOS, a niche OS that's actually [been around for months and is a racist-minded OS](https://youtu.be/7uLzaKlZSQQ?t=15).

Comment: @Cœur The votes are most likely due to Meta effect, in my opinion, since that question was linked from Carroll's request to undelete. 9 votes out of over 350 views when the majority of views probably came from Meta vistors (who are more active that the general user population) doesn't seem particularly suspicious to me. That Meta post even made it into the Hot Meta sidebar. Note that the question itself has 30 votes (14 up, 16 down).

Comment: @HansPassant I blame Meta effect for the closures. *All* of them were closed within the last 10 hours of right now, and there are several users that are listed as close voters on multiple questions. (Some are even commenting here.)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth, the area51 proposal was closed as dupe of SU, so then the best way would be to migrate to SU I think.

Comment: Also I think its worth noting that he also created the tag, in case no one else picked up on that