# Niche technologies and question acceptance and moderation on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, support, outsourcing

Niche technologies have a smaller pool of users, and a smaller yet pool of experts. **That however shouldn't determine whether or not a question is on topic here.** Sorry for the lengthy post, but let's look at a few examples here,

---

**Tab Completion**

- **Acceptable** *[How do I make Vim do normal (Bash-like) tab completion for file names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526858/how-do-i-make-vim-do-normal-bash-like-tab-completion-for-file-names)*
- **Acceptable** *[How to make PowerShell tab completion work like Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264655/how-to-make-powershell-tab-completion-work-like-bash)*
- **Unacceptable** *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239212/how-do-i-enable-tab-completion-in-templeos*

I wanted to get what I was used to (Bash-like tab completion) out of TempleOS. Unlike with Vim, there isn't a better place to ask the question (vim.se), nor is it documented (`:he wildcard`).

Let's just go from the official descriptions of these,

- [source](https://www.vim.org/) Vim: *Vim - the ubiquitous text editor. Vim is a highly configurable text editor for efficiently creating and changing any kind of text.*
- [source](http://templeos.holyc.xyz/Wb/Doc/Requirements.html) TempleOS *User Skills Required * Knowledge of the C programming language.*

TempleOS is certainly more of a tool for programmers than Vim and has a higher percentage of users that are programmers.

---

**Missing source that was previously in core distribution**

- **Acceptable** *[Error "Unable to find a source package for r-base" on Debian Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29331132/error-unable-to-find-a-source-package-for-r-base-on-debian-testing)*
- **Acceptable** *[Unable to find a source package for pidgin (Linux Mint)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940834/unable-to-find-a-source-package-for-pidgin-linux-mint)*
- **Unacceptable** *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50264004/does-templeos-5-03-have-after-egypt-and-other-utilities*

Recently it seems TempleOS moved a lot of packages (which are actually source code) outside of the core distribution. Unable to find them I asked a question, and got a great answer.

---

**Adding on "supplementation features"**

- **Acceptable** [How do I turn a Windows feature on/off from the command line in Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35479080/how-to-turn-windows-feature-on-off-from-command-line-in-windows-10)
- **Unacceptable** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50266458/how-do-you-use-supplimental-isos-with-templeos

Now that I know TempleOS has broken apart many things from the main/CORE distribution, I need to understand how to install them. The question is primary how do I get those things into the Virtual Box image and add them to TempleOS. You can't exactly share-with-your-desktop, and it doesn't have a network stack. What is the supported mechanism for bringing in external data into the operating system? Or, do I have to rebuild an ISO with all the supplemental data I have and install that?

Sit for a second back and grok this. People closed this one for it being **general computing hardware and software**, yet none of the people that have voted to close it have *any* experience with TempleOS.

---

**Kernel / OS version**

- **Acceptable** [Where do I find the version of a Linux kernel source tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151694/where-to-find-the-version-of-a-linux-kernel-source-tree)
- **Acceptable** [Which version of Python do I have installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917885/which-version-of-python-do-i-have-installed)
- **Unacceptable** https://stackoverflow.com/q/50257134/124486

Not knowing anything about the version of the operating system I was running, I wanted to figure it out. Despite the fact that it's undocumented in TempleOS, and there was no manual to read the question was closed. For comparison, both of these things are *well* documented with Linux and Python.

---

**Open Source Operating system**

- **Acceptable** [Where is the source code for PyPI, the Python package index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741069/where-is-the-source-code-for-pypi-the-python-package-index)
- **Unacceptable** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50242900/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-for-templeos

I can understand not wanting to look for something because often times the pursuit **can not be definitively answered**. From the close reason,

> "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to **attract opinionated answers and spam.** Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

But that's not always the case. If something is targeting "user-programmers" and known to be open source, and you can't find the source or you can't find the repository -- and the user has looked for it, it seems perfectly acceptable to ask where that repository is. Like all things, it may change but it can be definitively answered at a point in time, and in my case, I contend it requires an expert to do so. **Prove me wrong**.

## Not Just TempleOS

Ok, so at this point you may think the problem is just TempleOS, but **it's not**. I had the same problem with Forth, a language that has no ability to do networking when I asked for a [networking library, or how I would do networking with FORTH](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49602466/revisions). Use a language that predates IP; this is a real problem: though I can understand if you're a PHP user having no experience with this problem.

Let's review a comment from that thread,

> I think there are some here on SO who cruise questions looking superficially for cases that don't match the "SO standard" and down-vote and/or vote to close without taking into account any special considerations. I suspect, in this case, they don't even know or use Forth. Here on SO I think there are maybe one or two users total who know enough Forth to answer anything but fairly trivial questions about it, unfortunately. – lurker Apr 2 at 11:10

## What I would like to come out of this.

First, I would like [my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/templeos) to be reopened, but that's not my expectation. I feel they're in good form, and moreover that they'll help out people that want to learn about TempleOS, or operating systems and older technologies (osdevers).

But, really we need to seriously consider how to restructure these close votes. Not to name drop -- this involves two diamond moderators and many others who do this habitually, some are even self-appointed unelected sheriffs of the wild-wild west that gloat about it in their profiles. It's easy to close things. It's **hard** to get them reopened. It's stressful for those asking questions to come in with this mentality. It requires a thick skin to come out to meta and bring these forward every time, and it makes the process **needlessly exclusionary**. Who wants to know how meta works, technically and culturally when they just want to ask tech questions? The current culture of the close brigade is one of non-rotating jurors who often come from a narrow walk and bring pretension and enjoy the power play of moderation.

Though I have solutions, I've left them all out so we're not voting on that here.

## Summary of Activities

I learned a new operating system TempleOS catered to user-programmers. I [created a tag for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/templeos). I asked 10 questions on a new technology and seeded the tag: **90% (9/10) questions were closed.** The remaining question is one vote away. These were not *typical* questions either. I provided screen shots, text-translations, background information -- far exceeding the typical quality of question we get. Moreover, I have been contributing for almost 9 years on this site and am in the top 1% (of like four sites on the network) and have like 30,000 experience here. This is tremendously discouraging, and I hope we can change something.

## Not a dupe

> [Why we're not customer support for [your favorite company]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

TempleOS isn't a company. It's a free operating system in the public domain created for user-programmers. This is not applicable at all to this question.

Comment: Why is it so important to you to ask questions that you know are off topic, instead of going to a site where those questions are actually on topic?  I'd think a user with as much experience on the site as you would know better than just just repeatedly ask questions you know you shouldn't, only to complain about questions *you know merit closure* getting closed.  The fact that there are enough people voting to close questions to ensure every single off topic question gets closed doesn't mean it's a bad thing that some of them *do* get closed.

Comment: Note, that some of the questions you compare with are more than 6 years old. The culture has changed since then. I also have the feeling that you are comparing questions that are not equal. For example, "Kernel / OS version": 1) Asks to find version of linux **source code** when developing. 2) Asks about the version of a programming environment. 3) Asks about the version of the running OS. Not related to programming. Which version of Windows do I currently use would also be off-topic.

Comment: Consider this: I don't agree they're off topic. And, you haven't said where one should go to ask them: not that it has anything to do with whether or not they're on topic here, which I believe they are.

Comment: @user1114: I disagree unless you define the operating system as "software tools commonly used by programmers"

Comment: Unless the claim here is that the entire OS is an IDE... yeah it seems like this is on the line at best.

Comment: @user1114: Then the questions should be asked in a way that is related to programming. "How do I find out what version of TempleOS I am running?" is (imho) not related to programming at all. If you ask: "I have the Temple OS source, how do I find out which version it relates to", then it would be on-topic.

Comment: @BDL everyone has the TempleOS source code, you're literally running JIT'd C. It compiles when it executes. Have you used TempleOS?

Comment: A brief reply: Just because a question hasn't been closed yet does not mean it's on-topic here. You start with a wrong premise. From a wrong premise everything can follow; it is just useles for a logical conclusion.

Comment: Another problem with most of the TempleOS questions is the way how they ask the question. Although the topic itself could be on-topic, asking "Where do I find the documentation to do X" is off-topic > request for off-site resource. "How do I do X" could be on-topic.

Comment: @EvanCarroll So you're telling me that you think that resource requests are on topic here?  You've got questions closed for that exact reason, so I'm assuming that you're *aware* that those questions are not actually on topic.  Your statement that you wish questions were on topic, even though you know they are off topic, doesn't change the fact that you *asked those questions even knowing they are off topic*.  If you want what is on topic here to change, then propose a change on meta (after doing your research because **lots** of people have requested questions like that be allowed).

Comment: @BDL I have no defense to that, perhaps the questions could have been worded better or reformed by others that know TempleOS or are better with the semantics of the SO rules. I just tried to make the questions clear to the people reading them. I agree and I'm open to criticism. They problem here is I was give no guidence and **90%** of my questions were closed, maybe even **100%** by the end of the day, and they're remarkably routine for the site.

Comment: @EvanCarroll would you consider TempleOS questions to fall under "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"

Comment: You have been on Stack Overflow for four times as long as I have and have six times as much rep as I have. You should know not to post such blatantly off-topic questions. If you had been a new user, you would have likely gotten a question ban for this.

Comment: @RobertColumbia, Servy, ryanyuyu: I don't think that accusations to the op have any value in this discussion. I tend to say that these things are border-line rude. Can we please discuss the matter at hand without derailing into these niceties?

Comment: Asking me to answer that is slightly unfair -- it's a *highly* compound question. TempleOS was useful for me to understand a past generation of Operating Systems, like the Commodore 64 which predate my own experiences. It was a tool for that, and it was designed that way for me to become a "user-programmer". Asking me if it's practical is rather pointless. It's somewhat more practical than ASP Classic, VBScript, Excel, and [crackme challenges](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Crackme+is%3Aquestion) all of which are on topic here.

Comment: @BDL: I consider high-rep users asking apparent off-topic questions an actual problem and in some way much more rude than users pointing out this fact. That said: they indeed do have a point.

Comment: Just for the sake of argument I reread all of your questions replacing TempleOs by iOS/Linux/Windows, *just as I did when close-voting them*. Didn't make them on-topic. And as for your last comment. A tag is never on-topic. Questions are, or not. Really, to me the problem is not that TempleOs is a niche, I guess there are more niches. There is no connection between "niche-ness" and question acceptance.

Comment: We disagree. I hope others see that I have (a) provided ample evidence to show that at the least there are a slew of similar questions that are not acted against (b) that those closing have targeted a specific tag, batch, or user or that those asking questions on a specific topic as I have are likely to perceive it that way and that it is going to push away users (c) their area of expertise (in your case Microsoft, but generally not-TempleOS) is ridden with things they should clean up before they turn their guns to things they don't understand or have never used:

Comment: There are plenty of "niche" topics that are welcomed on Stack Overflow. VB6 is still on-topic, as is 6502 assembly, and all versions of COBOL.

Comment: @gnat what does that have to do with anything? It's a public domain operating system. It's like saying `We're not customer support for [linux]`... that's just arrogant. We're a community of enthusiasts. Others are answering the TempleOS questions.

Comment: it has everything to do with what you are trying to get here, namely turn Stack Overflow into support desk for  [your favorite OS]

Comment: So what about removing all [windows] and [linux] questions? Are you just abusing the flagging system? Because it's certainly not off-topic to ask questions about an operating system created for user-programmers.

Comment: I've been reading into it, and counting TempleOS as software for programmers might actually be reasonable. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TempleOS): _The software is a ......  PC operating system for recreational programming._

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth and are task made within it are "unique to software development"? Look, Kali sells itself as "a Debian-derived Linux distribution **designed for digital forensics and penetration testing**", yet Kali questions tend to be almost universally bad end user questions.

Comment: That's not specific at all. How do you expect to get a useful response when you're not explaining what Kali questions you're comparing to? Kali is a distribution of end-user software that sits aside from a Kernel, a compiler, and a file system. It's a collection of stuff that's focus on "digital forensics and penetration testing" is tailored to a skill, but not programming. TempleOS explicitly is all off that stuff. Everything you run on TempleOS is JIT compiled. It's closer to booting into a JVM and compiling and calling system utilities than a flavor of Debian.

Comment: @Braiam My comment is more of a response to the previous comments by BDL and BradleyDotNET, that counting the OS as a tool commonly used by programmers might be reasonable. As you properly pointed out, however, the question also has to be about a problem unique to software development, and that might not be true for these questions. As for Kali... Well... Let's just not go there...

Comment: Kali `man ls` shows a document for end users. In TempleOS [`Man("Dir");`](https://templeos.holyc.xyz/Wb/Kernel/BlkDev/DskDirB.html) takes you the `Dir()` function in a Kernel library. And, it's not even really documented, except to say "List directory."

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth well, computers are tools commonly used by programmers, yet I don't see anyone rushing to ask "why my pc doesn't boot". The entire thing should be read as a double conditional statement.

Comment: We have two tags related to that when it involves code and expertise -- [tag:bootloader] [tag:boot], and also grub, and x11 (which Terry Davis wrote himself (he has his own 640x480 graphical system, and his own hand rolled boot loader).

Comment: @Braiam Yes, I know it's not enough to make it on-topic, and I agree, and that's what I said in my last comment. I'm just saying, I commented this to respond to [these](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367693/niche-technologies-and-question-acceptance-and-moderation-on-stackoverflow#comment587911_367693) [two](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367693/niche-technologies-and-question-acceptance-and-moderation-on-stackoverflow#comment587912_367693) comments

Answer (score -27, accepted):

As demonstrated the policies of this website are inherently inconsistent and unfair. There is nothing you can do about it.

- Despite [Unix And Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), [Ubuntu StackExchange](https://askubuntu.com/), [Apple StackExchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) all representing communities centered around Operating Systems, and not end-use or programming -- TempleOS can not find a home on its own Stack Exchange nor on a combined [OS Dev](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367704/124486) Stack Exchange.
- Despite having **direct** analogs with more mainstream products, the questions are considered "off-topic."
- Despite being explicitly for programmers (requiring knowledge of C), and unlike VIM which is just a Text Editor that programmers happen to use, TempleOS is not "programmer-enough" for Stack Overflow.
- Despite having elections, and claiming to be *"run by you"* there is no list of the rules, sentences are mutable and change at the whims of StackExchange, you'll get banned again after a ban expires because it "wasn't enough." And, moderator elections are a top-down procedure. My own nomination was yanked.
- Despite having close "reasons" it's just the will of an entitled cabal. Look even this question is tagged for being a dupe of *"Why we're not customer support for [your favorite company] 1 answer"*: it's a meta joke. I flagged to get that notice removed (because it's an abuse of the system) and that flag was denied.

The questions have no home on the network but not for a lack of subject-matter adhesion or quality, just because excluding people and content is what evil corps do. So what can we do,

- We can hope the Stack Overflow alt-right rage quits and leaves Terry and everyone else alone. Come on symbolic Code of Conduct and fragile masculinity!
- We can hope that enough people [opt-out of the Arbitration Clause](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310061/electronic-opt-out-correcting-miscommunication-and-additional-questions-answer) so we can one day sue the billionaire overloads in a class action law suit, expropriate their yachts, and retire in Bora Bora, [etc.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9AjkUyX0rVw)

Comment: lovely... you're definitely showing good faith and not riling up the community against you by reacting this way to people disagreeing with your PoV... I understand you may be aggravated by the reaction, but pushing back like this will get you nowhere, whether the initial point you're making is valid or not....

Comment: "My own nomination was yanked." Well, no. It was yanked because of [the written procedures that were voted on and generally well-liked on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year).

Comment: "My own nomination was yanked": I read your nomination text (I should have copy/pasted it somewhere) and seriously: it was ludicrious. Talking about being good friends with Jeff Artwood, this Trump quip, ... what did you expect?

Answer (score 33):

The thing you're having difficulty understanding is that Stack Overflow does allow some questions about tools and operating systems. However, these questions must be about either programming tools (IDEs, compilers, etc.), tools that non-programmers could use but are primarily/frequently used by programmers (Git, Vim, etc.), or something of the kind.

Just because it happens under an operating system that's open source does not make it a valid Stack Overflow question.

Given that, let's walk down this list example by example:

> **Tab Completion**
>
> - **Acceptable** [How do I make Vim do normal (Bash-like) tab completion for file names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526858/how-do-i-make-vim-do-normal-bash-like-tab-completion-for-file-names)
> - **Acceptable** [How to make PowerShell tab completion work like Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264655/how-to-make-powershell-tab-completion-work-like-bash)
> - **Unacceptable** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239212/how-do-i-enable-tab-completion-in-templeos
>
> I wanted to get what I was used to (Bash-like tab completion) out of
>   TempleOS. Unlike with VIM, there isn't a better place to ask the
>   question (vim.se), nor is it documented (`:he wildcard`)

Vim is a tool primarily used by programmers, so questions about its operation are allowed (though vim.se is the preferred place). PowerShell is *arguably* a tool used primarily by programmers. While non-programmers could use it, most people who do are programmers or IT personnel.

TempleOS's shell is just... TempleOS's shell. Any user of TempleOS could have such a question; it's not specific to programmers. Unless you're saying that only programmers are users of TempleOS.

> **Missing source that was previously in core distribution**
>
> - **Acceptable** [Error "Unable to find a source package for r-base" on Debian Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29331132/error-unable-to-find-a-source-package-for-r-base-on-debian-testing)
> - **Acceptable** [Unable to find a source package for pidgin (Linux Mint)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940834/unable-to-find-a-source-package-for-pidgin-linux-mint)
> - **Unacceptable** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50264004/does-templeos-5-03-have-after-egypt-and-other-utilities
>
> Recently it seems TempleOS moved a lot of packages (which are actually source code) outside of the core distribution. Unable to find them I asked a question, and got a great answer.

Instructions on how to install programming tools and environments are on-topic.

As I understand it, *After Egypt* is just a regular utility for the OS, not a programming tool or environment. As such, instructions on installing it or any other generic utilities are off-topic.

> **Adding on "supplementation features"**
>
> - **Acceptable** [How do I turn a Windows feature on/off from the command line in Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35479080/how-to-turn-windows-feature-on-off-from-command-line-in-windows-10)
> - **Unacceptable** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50266458/how-do-you-use-supplimental-isos-with-templeos
>
> Now that I know TempleOS has broken a part many things from the
>   main/CORE distribution, I need to understand how to install them. The
>   question is primary how do I get those things into the Virtual Box
>   Image and add them to TempleOS. You can't exactly
>   share-with-your-desktop, and it doesn't have a Network Stack. What is
>   the supported mechanism for bringing in external data into the
>   operating system? Or, do I have to rebuild an ISO with all the
>   supplemental data I have and install that?
>
> Sit for a second back and grok this, people closed this one for it
>   being **general computing hardware and software** yet none of the
>   people that have voted to close it have *any* experience with
>   TempleOS.

That's because it *is* general computing software. The task you're asking about is not *specific to programmers* working in TempleOS in any way. As such, it's off-topic for Stack Overflow.

The Windows 10 feature question... that one is highly debatable. That sounds like it ought to be on Super User.

> **Kernel / OS version**
>
> - **Acceptable** [Where do I find the version of a Linux kernel source tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151694/where-to-find-the-version-of-a-linux-kernel-source-tree)
> - **Acceptable** [Which version of Python do I have installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917885/which-version-of-python-do-i-have-installed)
> - **Unacceptable** https://stackoverflow.com/q/50257134/124486
>
> Not knowing anything about the version of the operating system I was
>   running. I wanted to figure it out. Despite the fact that it's
>   undocumented in TempleOS, and there was no manual to read the question
>   was closed. For comparison, both of these things are *well* documented
>   with Linux and Python.

One question is about getting the version of the Linux kernel from the source tree; that's something programmers do. The next asks about getting the version of Python from within Python; that's something programmers do.

You asked about getting TempleOS's version from the shell. That's something users of TempleOS do; it is in no way specific to programmers.

> **Open Source Operating system**
>
> - **Acceptable** [Where is the source code for PyPI, the Python package index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741069/where-is-the-source-code-for-pypi-the-python-package-index)
> - **Unacceptable** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50242900/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-for-templeos
>
> I can understand not wanting to look for something because often times
>   the pursuit **can not be definitively answered**. From the close
>   reason,
>
> > "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
> >     Overflow as they tend to **attract opinionated answers and spam.**
> >     Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
> >     it."
>
> But that's not always the case. If something is targeting
>   "user-programmers" and known to be open source, and you can't find the
>   source or you can't find the repository -- and the user has looked for
>   it, it seems perfectly acceptable to ask where that repository is.
>   Like all things, it may change but it can be definitively answered at
>   a point in time, and in my case, I contend it requires an expert to do
>   so. **Prove me wrong**.

Both of those questions are asking for off-site resources. Both of those questions should be closed.

---

> I had the same problem with Forth, a language that has no ability to do Networking when I asked for a [networking library, or how I would do networking with Forth](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49602466/revisions).

And we don't allow questions asking for off-site resources, as previously indicated. And if it were just "how I would do networking with Forth", that's simply too broad.

---

This is not a matter of "niche technologies"; it is a matter of poor questions.

---

It seems to me that you're trying to use TempleOS as the "programming boat meme". That is, you're effectively trying to claim that *everything* that happens on TempleOS, every kind of use of the operating system, is programming.

That is absurd. I don't care if all uses of TempleOS involve C. It's not "programming" to ask the OS what its version is; that's use of the OS. It doesn't matter how the OS coughs up that version number. Even if it actually goes and reads its own source code to get the version number, you're still performing a user operation, not a programming task.

TempleOS doesn't get to exempt itself from our rules because of its interface.

Comment: *"VIM is a tool primarily used by programmers"* what percentage of VIM's users are programmers. It's a text-editor. Certainly not all of them. What percentage of TempleOS's users are programmers? It explicitly requires you to be a programmer: *"User Skills Required
* Knowledge of the C programming language."* https://templeos.holyc.xyz/Wb/Doc/Requirements.html How is that "not a tool for programmers?" You got a lot about what Temple OS is, have you ever even used it?

Comment: *"You asked about getting TempleOS's version from the shell. That's something users of TempleOS do; it is in no way specific to programmers."* the TempleOS kernel is released with the operating system. That's really splitting hairs. The chosen answer, the one I provided, actually shows that -- the variables are defined in the kernel's source files.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: Are you using that programming language to *program*? And no, that's not a rhetorical question. If you're using a programming language for non-programming duties (like executing commands on an OS), that doesn't make it a programming task.

Comment: No. I'm using it to program. I want to learn how the Oracle works. That's why the Temple is there. I want to see the code. I want to communicate with it myself. None of this is documented, but it's in every video and news article. I'm an inquisitive programmer simply doing the programmer thing.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: If your question had been for *any other operating system*, it would be off topic. Why is TempleOS special? Because it's Open Source? We have plenty of open source operating system questions that are off topic. Because it uses C somewhere? So what? Bash and other shell scripting languages are Turning complete, and not every question that does shell scripting is appropriate for SO.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: "*I'm using it to program. I want to learn how the Oracle works.*" That's not programming; that's learning about how a program works. It's not the same thing at all.

Comment: This is **your** argument. My argument is that it wouldn't be off topic if it was *any other operating system* so I showed you an example where they ask the same question on Linux. Your response is that the version requested on Linux is pertaining to the kernel. So you're hanging your hat on there being a difference between the kernel and the operating system -- that's not so. They're versioned the same...

Comment: But even if they weren't versioned the same, in order to ask an informed question you must know how to collect the information for the question. If I want to ask a question about how my version of TempleOS is packaged, I'll need to be able to provide some information in my question. I needed a starting a point. I needed to know how my educational tool, for programmers, was versioned so I could ask a question about that educational tool.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: "*Your response is that the version requested on Linux is pertaining to the kernel.*" No, my response is that it's pertaining to *a specific piece of source code*, a specific source tree. That is, given this block of source code, how do you tell what version it is. That's different from "I'm in the OS shell; how do I get the version?"

Comment: Why is that different when the OS shell itself, gets the version from the kernel source tree itself which is shipped with the OS? (Must be hard to argue this case when you don't use the software, so I do somewhat pity the situation you've put yourself in)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170819/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-evan-carroll).

Comment: @EvanCarroll Regarding VIM: voted the 5th most popular development environment according to the latest SO developer survey (https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/#technology-most-popular-development-environments). It was even ranked higher the previous years. VIM was written for programmers.

Comment: What does that have to do with anything? I use Vi. It's useful. It's a tool "used by programmers, so questions about its operation are allowed." But it's also not used *just* by programmers. It has objective value for anyone who wants to edit text. TempleOS has almost no value for anyone "except" programmers, and as I said actually assumes you know how to program (unlike VIM).

Comment: Just to be clear I'm responding to "tool primarily used by programmers" which isn't referring to the amount of gross programmers that use the tool, but the percent of programmers out of the pool of people that use tool -- that ratio is higher with TempleOS.

Comment: Examples of VIM not used for programmers, https://leanpub.com/vim-for-writers https://opensource.com/article/17/2/vim-plugins-writers http://www.naperwrimo.org/wiki/index.php?title=Vim_for_Writers http://timotheepoisot.fr/2014/01/01/vim-writing-environment/

Comment: @EvanCarroll Just wanted to correct your first comment. Vim is not just a text editor. It's the fifth most popular development environment. So to answer "what percentage of VIM's users are programmers": a lot of them. And can you please add the user when replying in comments? I didn't get notified.

Comment: @ModusTollens by the same regard, Windows is the most popular development operating system (your source) and it has more developers than VIM. Clearly: it's not the gross popularity but the ratio of the users that we should be focusing on.

Comment: @EvanCarroll You linked to a text showing how to configure vim to be good for writing text because a good _code editor_ does not make a good text editor. Anyway, I'm not going to argue about editors here in the comments. Just wanted to correct the vim statement. Done.

Comment: Cool, that guy disagrees and thinks it makes a good text editor. You can message/troll him though. Just wanted to correct the vim statement. Done.

Comment: @EvanCarroll `"tool primarily used by programmers" which isn't referring to the amount of gross programmers that use the tool, but the percent of programmers out of the pool of people that use tool -- that ratio is higher with TempleOS` - That's an oversimplification. If I (a programmer) write a tool that allows me to draw stick figures of unicorns, and I am the only user of that tool, then it's vacuously true that 100% of users of the stick-figure-unicorn-tool are programmers, but it should be obvious that it's not what is meant by *"software tools commonly used by programmers"*.

Comment: So if 10 million programmers use it and 3 billion other people, it's on topic? Doesn't seem obvious to me. Moreover, TempleOS is an instructional tool, not a stick figure so that comment is tooootalllllyyy off. What do stick figures even have to do with this?

Comment: @EvanCarroll I didn't claim that the "amount of gross programmers" is all that counts. I only said that the percent of programmers out of the pool of people that use the tool cannot be the single factor that determines whether it's a "tool primarily used by programmers" or not. I also didn't say that "no third possibility is given". I just wanted to point out that this percentage cannot be the only determining factor. Can't say much about the actual topic, but it seems like you've managed to find an interesting corner case that interacts with the rules and conventions in a non-trivial way.

Comment: Well, I still think it's the single factor. That's my argument and I'm sticking to it. Is your stick figure a tool? Yes. Is 100% of the user base programmers? Yes. So I accept your premise and agree it's more of a "tool primarily used by programmers" then VIM. And, i'm the maintainer of a few vim plugins (still, I believe). You've sought to show my argument was flawed, seems defensible to me.

Comment: @EvanCarroll If you accept that my editor for drawing unicorns is a "tool primarily used by programmers" simply because I'm the only user *and* a programmer, then it shows only that your current interpretation of the phrase "tool primarily used by programmers" is absurd. If you are ready to accept absurd conclusions just so you can stick to your assumptions (to the above-mentioned ratio-criterion in particular), then I don't know how to proceed from here. So, you've managed to find an absurd interpretation of a vague phrase from Help page by dropping enough common-sense assumptions, now what?

Comment: We have lots of tools that are primarily used by programmers to draw unicorns and they're more for programmers than VIM is, MIT Scratch and this for example: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-god-its-full-of-unicorns Anyway, this is removed and pedantic. TempleOS is an education tool for written primarily for programmers, though it seems drawing tools for programmers would also satisfy the definition (aside from your anti-drawing anti-unicorn elitism).

Comment: @EvanCarroll that's only 1 part of the on-topic conditionals, your question has to be about something unique to software development. Almost all programmers use browsers, text processors and OS's, yet that doesn't make all questions about those browsers, text processors and OS on topic. Just because it's used by programmers doesn't mean it is on topic, your question has to be about software deveopment too.

Comment: @ModusTollens remember that that survey is biased, it doesn't have external validation due the respondent being self-selected. Vim wasn't made for programmers, vim was made to improve vi feature set, and vi itself was to improve on ex. All of them were simply text editors with visual interfase.

Comment: @Braiam so that *may* be true. That at least makes sense. None of my questions were about Software Development, in the sense that I wasn't developing anything. They were about an investigation into a tool that was made to educate software developers. But that's a huge part of this site -- people asking for demos, examples, and asking abstract questions about principles and fundamentals.

Comment: @EvanCarroll only the last one is on topic, so long as is unique to software development.

Comment: @Braiam Yes I know that vim was an improvement (Vi iMproved) of the vi editor. I've used vi for writing source code when we had nothing better. Then vim came along with improvements _for writing source code_. It's quite off topic to discuss this here, but as one reference see this discussion with the developer: http://www.hostingadvice.com/blog/vim-creator-champions-charityware/.

Comment: @EvanCarroll It's intentionally removed and pedantic. As I said, I know almost nothing about TempleOS, so instead I wanted to focus on one single decision criterion. The thought experiment with unicorn-editor illustrates that the application of the ratio-criterion alone can lead to absurd outcomes. It's not about anti-drawing anti-unicorn elitism ;) , the same argument works for any other software: *"For each tool T written by programmer P, if the set of users of T is {P}, then 100% of users of T are programmers, therefore T is on-topic"* -- can we agree that this is an absurd statement?

Comment: Seems logical to me.

Comment: I suppose you need to be a lawyer to ask for help on SO nowadays. It has grown too big for its own good.