# Can all of the deleted/closed TempleOS questions be moved to Super User?

Tags: discussion, support, migration

I've got a ton of, now censored, questions on [TempleOS](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/templeos/). Is it possible to liberate them and set them free at Super User? I think they'll find a welcoming home there and will be able to continue to benefit programmers seeking that information.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50264004/does-templeos-5-03-have-after-egypt-and-other-utilities
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50257134/how-do-i-find-out-what-version-of-templeos-i-am-running
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50259091/how-do-i-export-the-files-of-templeos-to-the-host-operating-system
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50266458/how-do-you-use-supplimental-isos-with-templeos
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50260790/templeos-sound-with-virtualbox
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50262702/process-management-in-templeos-listing-and-killing-processes
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239317/is-there-anyway-to-correct-from-this-screen
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50242900/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-for-templeos
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239415/why-cant-templeos-run-on-modern-x86-64-machines
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239212/how-do-i-enable-tab-completion-in-templeos

## Update

This [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286934/correct-workflow-for-migrating-a-deleted-question) speaks to the question and says,

> If your question was deleted with no answers, you can just repost it yourself. There's no need to involve moderators or any other members of the community in an action you can take yourself.

These questions, most of them anyway, have answers that are upvoted. So I'm wanting to get them migrated with the questions.

Comment: I did ask them here. I asked 10 questions and they were all, 100% of them, closed. This is what the SE moderator wanted, so I'm giving him permission to do it I guess.

Comment: @yivi see this link for more information https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367693/124486 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367663/124486

Comment: @yivi they were asking earlier if I would be ok with it? If they were asking me if I would be ok with the migraiton and I answered that I'd rather have the conversation on meta, and now I want to answer that question with "yes" what do you call that which I'm giving? Permission? Approval? etc

Comment: @yivi I already asked them here, you want me to duplicate them on SuperUser and lose the *massively* upvoted answers on them?

Comment: related: "[Correct workflow for migrating a deleted question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286934/9614249)"

Comment: @yivi you think it's fair to the person answering to lose the contribution because of the subjective interpretation (and application) of rules on StackOverflow. Anyway, my request is for a migration. I doubt SuperUser will care much if an answer has 10 upvotes.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic that's a good post, my questions have answers and so my read of that is that asking for the migration is the right thing?

Comment: If any of these posts are more than 3 months old, they're not going anywhere.  Migrations must occur within 90 days of posting.

Comment: @YvetteColomb how is a request for migration off-topic? Can I get the migration then?

Comment: Moderators generally don't migrate closed and deleted questions to another site. We're pretty reluctant to migrate questions, overall, unless we see evidence that they would be responded to well on the target site. My recommendation would be to first make sure the questions were within the scope of Super User, then re-ask them there if appropriate. Regarding these questions being "censored", no moderator cast a single close or delete vote on them. All were removed based entirely on community votes.

Comment: I just want a migration -- not personal attacks, how about you migrate and delete this if you feel it's a burden to the community? It's certainly not "off-topic" to ask for a migration though.

Comment: If memory serves, the votes get reset to zero when the question is migrated anyway.

Comment: @BradLarson the StackExchange employees disagree (afaik). They said OS Dev a proposal on Area 51 wasn't valid because these questions are on top at SuperUser.

Comment: @RobertHarvey then all is good, let's get it done. They're good questions no one disputes that. They're just not on topic here because an operating system that requires C and is created as an education tool for programmers is less on-topic than the performance of Clippy, https://stackoverflow.com/q/6296454/124486

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277872/remove-the-mention-of-super-user-from-the-standard-off-topic-close-reasons

Comment: @EvanCarroll Provide a list in the question or flag each individually for migration, that will be the easiest thing. Mind you, we are cautious about migrating. The other sites have made it clear they don't want low quality stuff, but we can get someone from SU to review the posts. Tidy up the wording of your question and I'll reopen it.

Comment: @yivi because then I have to attribute the poster (more work for me then the migration would be), and the poster themselves isn't the beneficiary of their own work. Moreover, directly quoting another answer without improving it is *highly* looked down upon. What I don't understand, why is someone who has less than 50 contributions on this site so invested in denying my contributions from being migrated.

Comment: @YvetteColomb sure thing will do it now.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: Just a couple, so that we can review them.  Note that if they're over 90 days old, there's nothing we can do; the tools will not allow us to migrate.

Comment: @RobertHarvey updated. =) Keep in mind if they're not ontopic here, and they're not on topic there then I expect your support when I ask for OS Dev, a community which could clarify this horrendous and tragic confusion facing the TempleOS community.

Comment: @yivi I'm not sure what you are trying to say here, but it seems you don't understand migration. Evan cannot just copy and paste questions and answers to another site that other people have posted. It's a valid question to ask, I took him to task about how he asked it, not the question itself.

Comment: @Yvette, content is still under the same license. Why not? (Not picking an argument, honest question). And the “I’ve got a ton” line made me think those where Evan’s questions anyway.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: Drama aside, it's up to the target community to decide whether they're on-topic or not.  Not every question has a home on the Stack Exchange network, and we're not going to go out of our way to find a home for these when you can simply repost them.

Comment: I hate drama too.

Comment: @yivi the attribution still belongs to the poster, which is hard, as the content is being deleted and the users may not be on the new migrated site. It's just not something that we generally do. As it is if a user on SO posts an answer that someone posted as a comment or part of a question, the etiquette is to post it as an answer with attribution and flag for a mod to make the answer a community wiki so they get no rep for it, This is within the same Q&A set.

Comment: But @Yvette, even if the posts aren't Evan's, wouldn't re-posting these (copying and pasting them) providing a link to the (deleted) post as attribution comply with the CC-BY-SA license? I would have thought it would, although attribution in the case of deleted posts is rather unusual I guess.

Comment: @yivi the target sites usually don't want our stuff. I recommend you browse meta about this, you can also ask a question, though it may be a dupe. Read my answer here and navigate around.

Comment: @yivi migration is less hassle for everyone if the post is "migratable" (I made that word up) Anyway my curious friend. I have to go, it's late. Read on young padawan.. go forth and absorb the force that is meta :D

Answer (score 6):

Ok the disputed questions have been manually undeleted so the target site can view them. One of the mods on SuperUser told me that they seem very specific and he's not sure if they will be on topic for that site. He advised that a meta post is asked on SuperUser.

I've also gone to the SuperUser chat room and [asked users](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44644212#44644212) in the chat room to review your posts.

At this stage I would recommend you ask on Super User Meta. As mentioned in the comments, any unanswered posts can be deleted here and asked on another Stack Exchange site, providing they're on topic for that site.

In future flag only to have answered posts migrated and just delete unanswered off topic questions.

The mods here are reluctant to migrate content from this site to other sites, unless the directive comes from an experienced user on the other site, as the other sites do not like having our [off-topic scraps pushed onto them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277872/remove-the-mention-of-super-user-from-the-standard-off-topic-close-reasons).

Comment: Never one to let to others down, I have a drama-free clean and to the point post on meta.superuser.com for this. Probably the best they've ever had. And, they're about to get the 10 best questions they ever had if they want them. https://meta.superuser.com/q/13082/11116

Comment: I'll try to review them if another mod dosen't. I have reservations, and would not recommend we move them all. on a quick glance at least one of them is essentially a learning material rec for example.